# Java JSOUP lib (1.6.3) removes <style> tag

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm using JSOUP to remove unwanted tags. I added `style` tag to the white list but it removes contents of that! why?

Original:

```
<html><head><style>body{height:100%;color:#333333;font-size:8pt;font-family:Arial;}</style></head><body><div dir="rtl"><style>body{background:black;}
</style>
<p><span style="background-color:#FFFF00">bhkgkhgkhghkgkgkg</span></p>
</div></body></html>
```

After Cleaning:

```
<html><head><style></style></head><body><div dir="rtl"><style>body{background:black;}
</style>
<p><span style="background-color:#FFFF00">bhkgkhgkhghkgkgkg</span></p>
</div></body></html>
```

Code:

```
Whitelist myWhite = new Whitelist()
                .addTags(
                        "a", "b", "blockquote", "br", "caption", "cite", "code", "col",
                        "colgroup", "dd", "div", "dl", "dt", "em", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6",
                        "i", "img", "li", "ol", "p", "pre", "q", "small", "strike", "strong",
                        "sub", "sup", "table", "tbody", "td", "tfoot", "th", "thead", "tr", "u",
                        "ul", "font", "span", "hr", "form", "input", "option", "select", "textarea", "style")

String safe = Jsoup.clean(unSafe, myWhite);
```

Comment: for me this works just fine. What version of Jsoup are you using?

Comment: It works for me either, with version 1.8.1

Comment: @luksch its version was old (1.6.3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the issue is related to its version and I could have resolved that by upgrading its version to (1.8.3);